# mysqli_query does not work with a string but with a number

Tags: string, mysqli, numbers, integer

```
$a = '123';
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `accounts` SET `solved` = $a WHERE `username` = $username");
```

This does work.

```
$a = 'qwert';
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `accounts` SET `solved` = $a WHERE `username` = $username");
```

This does not work.

`solved` is a tinytext in `accounts`. If `$a` is a string, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to surround `$a` with single quotes:

```
$a = 'qwert';
mysqli_query($connect, 
             "UPDATE `accounts` SET `solved` = '$a' WHERE `username` = $username");
```